# Is it possible to have a race condition when composing into the same destination object in GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Let's say I have the following scenario:

There are two processes running at the exact same time. Both create temporary files and attempt to append them, via compose, to a shared destination file.

Process 1: creates a temp file (my_file1.txt) and does `compose(shared_file.txt, my_file1.txt) -> shared_file.txt`
Process 2: creates a temp file (my_file2.txt) and does `compose(shared_file.txt, my_file2.txt) -> shared_file.txt`

My hope is that `shared_file.txt` contains the content of `my_file1.txt` and `my_file2.txt`.

Is it possible that the result of `shared_file.txt` will contain only one of the temp files? Are there consistency checks within Google Cloud Storage that ensure that `compose` won't overwrite a file if it's changed *during* the composition?

If Google Cloud Storage locks the destination file during composition or linearly executes requests, I'd expect it always contains both `my_file1.txt` and `my_file2.txt` but with no guaranteed order. Otherwise, I'd expect that I'd need to use Generation Matching+Request retries to ensure both temp files are appended.

Answer (score 0):

The Compose API has an optional query parameter to control object creation:

> Setting ifGenerationMatch to 0 makes the operation succeed only if
> there is no live destination object

[Objects: compose](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose#parameters)

In your example, if process 1 succeeds, process 2 will fail if you specify the `ifGenerationMatch` header correctly. The reverse can be true pending which process completes first.

Comment: Updated the question to outline the goal. I was hoping the contents of `shared_file.txt` contained both files. I want to avoid a race condition in which it only contains one of the file's content because it clobbered the other file.

In this case, setting generation match+retry would work, but at that point, it would be easier to just make the requests run in a series.

Comment: After your edit. You must run two compose commands. The second command must run after the first completes.